# SharePoint Master Page modified SPSWC:SearchBoxEx not working correctly on each site

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have created a custom master page and have the follwoing code on the page:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
                            <SPSWC:SearchBoxEx id="SearchBox" 
                                RegisterStyles="false" 
                                TextBeforeDropDown="" 
                                TextBeforeTextBox="Search" 
                                TextBoxWidth="120" 
                                GoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/gosearch.png"
                                GoImageUrlRTL="/_layouts/images/gosearch.png" 
                                UseSiteDefaults="true" 
                                DropDownMode = "HideScopeDD" 
                                SuppressWebPartChrome="true" 
                                runat="server" 
                                WebPart="true" 
                                __WebPartId="{07E563F9-A259-4829-920F-03829BBC14D1}"
                                GoImageActiveUrl="/_layouts/images/gosearch.png" 
                                GoImageActiveUrlRTL="/_layouts/images/gosearch.png"/>    

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

On one site this code works correctly and on another it does not work and the default search box apears. I can not work out why this is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content in the contentplaceholder "PlaceHolderSearchArea" can be overwritten by a `<asp:Content />` element in a page layout. So check the page layouts you are using for the existance of an `<asp:Content/>` with the placeholder id "PlaceHolderSearchArea".

Comment: Where would I goto check out the page layouts?

Comment: Is your site a publishing site? 
You can open SharePoint designer and browse to /_catalogs/masterpage/